# How to uninstall server adapter?

Tags: eclipse, webserver, adapter

Eclipse EE Indigo. I installed additional server adapter and I don't know how uninstall them.

- they are not shown in the list of installed software
- uninstalling entire eclipse and installing it again does not help
- given server adapter is visible for Eclipse, because it can report conflicts for it (if any) and it is excluded from the list of adapters available to install

I don't know where I could find a list of **installed** server adapters with ability to uninstall them.

So -- how to uninstall server adapter?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reverting to an older eclipse configuration version :

Help > Installing New Software > Installation History > select a configuration before you added the server tools.

ps: please let me know if this worked or not and wether you found another working solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, at this point I reinstalled entire Eclipse :-( so I don't know if this works, but since it is very useful, if anyone report this as working (tested), I will also close this as solution. Is this OK with you?

Comment: Sure :), at least glad you fixed your problem, after all the reverting trick may be of use for other issues with Eclipse.
Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse EE Juno, I tried the trick of gaspyr to revert to an old configuration version and it worked even though the server adapter is not listed in the content installed from the installation history.

In my case, this was a pretty fresh install of Eclipse with very few configuration versions in the installation history and I knew when I had installed the server adapter. All I had to do is select a version prior to the server adapter installation.

If you are not sure what version it is, you may need to go through the installation history and revert to every versions, one by one and check each time if the server adapter is present or not. Afterwards, you may have to reinstall every plugins you had installed after the server adapter.

Answer (score 0):

This one is different from other software, but to remove a Server Runtime, go to Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environment, select the Server runtime you want to remove and click Remove.

That should take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty Easiest thing would be deleting all the related Jar files and folders manually from the `Eclipse` folder in the file system.